# C# Objectlistview group only specific rows

Tags: objectlistview

I'm trying to group only specific items on my list, to be more exact I try to group them only if the property "x" on my model "y" is filled. Other item's should not be grouped at all if property "x" is empty. Rigth now I have this code below:

```
olv.ShowGroups = true;
OLVColumn column = new OLVColumn("HiddenGroupColumn", "propertyX");
column.IsVisible = false;
column.GroupKeyGetter = delegate (object x)
{
    return ((modelY)x).propertyX;
};
olv.AlwaysGroupByColumn = column;
```

But it is sorting everything even the rows with empty propertyX value.

Is it somehow possible to group "only" rows that has propertyX filled and keep them inside list rather than adding them above or below the list?

For example:

| No | Name | PropertyX(Not an actual column just property in model) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | someStringHere |  |
| 2 | AnotherString |  |
| 3 | lorem | GRP1 |
| 4 | ipsum | GRP1 |
| 5 | asd |  |
| 6 | qwe |  |
| 7 | zxc | GRP2 |
| 8 | ttt | GRP2 |
| 9 | eee |  |

I tried to explain as much as I can, in this instance is it possible to group row 3-4 together and group row 7-8 together while keeping them in their current position and **NOT** grouping the ones that has Empty string on propertyX?

Comment: If you use the Grouping feature then everything must belong to a group.  This is the fundamental concept of the Grouping feature of ObjectListView.

Comment: so I can add row 1-2 into a group and make it look like non group, that way it might work. I'm gonna try this out